# "The size associated with an extended property cannot be more than 7,500 bytes" running `sp_addextendedproperty`

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've scripted a database and I ran the script to create a new database. But it throws an error with the message:

```
The size associated with an extended property cannot be more than 7,500 bytes.
```

How can i get rid of this problem?

Comment: Would be better if we see your script..

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue - generated from a VS2015 schema compare. Turns out all that extended property is doing is persisting the design of the View that you can see in SQL Management Studio. So you don't really need it.

Delete the extended property from the script and retry.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I noticed that a view was scripted with three extended properties, their names being:

- `MS_DiagramPane1`
- `MS_DiagramPane2`
- `MS_DiagramPaneCount`

I also modified the script code for the view to reflect several tables that have been renamed. I also renamed the table names where they occurred in the (large) `@value` parameter value passed to the system procedure `sp_addextendedproperty` for the first property defined in the script. The new table names are longer than the previous names so I suspect the parameter value now exceeds the 7,500 byte (character) limit.

But based on the property names, and after examining the `@value` values, it appears that whatever *uses* those properties (i.e. SQL Server Management Studio or other Microsoft tools) combines any number of 'diagram pane' properties. Here are the last sixteen lines of the `MS_DiagramPane1` property:

```
         Begin Table = "ROLES_1"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 292
               Left = 869
               Bottom = 387
               Right = 1059
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "GL_Journal_Code"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 1078
               Bottom = 118
               Right = 12
```

and the first ten lines of the `MS_DiagramPane2` property:

```
65
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
      End
   End
   Begin SQLPane = 
      PaneHidden = 
   End
```

By simply moving some of the content at the end of the parameter value for the first property to the beginning of the parameter value for the second property I was able to run the script without observing the error.

Comment: Seems to do the trick, just adjust the payload of an extended property value to match the limitation of 7500 bytes. I guess if you need more text then just add another method to further split the value for the extended properties content

Answer (score -1):

> How can i get rid of this problem?

You do not define an extended property that needs to be larger than 7500 bytes. Is that not obvious?

This is one of those "a page has 8kb, not more and not less" limitations which - sans overhead - runs down to a limit of 7500 bytes for an extended property. Need to store more? Well, not possible in the extended property.

Comment: That's not really a solution, instead you repeat the error message a bit rudely. Besides the extended info what "cannot be more than 7,500 bytes" means, an option how to work around or solve the error would have been more useful (see the other two answers).